# Conditional painting based on text of another cells word

Tags: microsoft-excel

Column V has five options from a drop-down:
"National, Junior National, Regional, Provisional, and "blank or no text".

Column A has a Code based on `Last Name (Column B) & First Name (Column C)` - concatenate first two letters

Can I add a paint or fill for Column A based on the word from Column V?

- National = Green,
- Junior National = Blue,
- Regional = Purple,
- Provisional = Orange,
- No Fill = Yellow.

What would the code line be?

Comment: Short answer: yes.

Answer (score 0):

Use Conditional Formatting on column A, select A, Conditional Formatting, New Rule, Use Formula to determine which cells to format, in the box that open write =V1="National" and Format Green
Repeat the same for each option with the other condition and color